# Распределение нагрузки в node JS

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, pm2

У меня есть парсер написаный на nodeJS. Как я понимаю вся нагрузка идёт на одно ядро?

Как тогда я могу распределить вычисления на два я ядра?

Сейчас я пробывал сделать это с помощью pm2:

```
  {
  "name" : "parser",
  "script" : "app.js",
  "exec_mode" : "cluster",
  "instances" : 2
},
```

Но если я задаю instances" : 2, то у меня просто выполняется 2 прецесса, т.е. просто напросто парсер делает одно и то же 2 раза.

А мне нужно снизить нагрузку.

Правильно ли я думаю? Если да, то как можно распределить процесс на 2 ядра?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что node.js изначально создавался как однопоточный асинхронный язык. Есть ряд модулей, делающие его многопоточным, в том числе с 10 версии в экспериментальном режиме добавили [worker_threads](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/415659/) которые позволяют распределять выполнение по потокам.

В случае с pm2, как вы правильно заметили, вы всего лишь запускаете два экземпляра одного и того же приложения.